# tmux - change status-bg when in an ssh session window

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to have a different `status-bg` color when in an ssh session?

Say I have the default green one, but would like it to turn red when in a ssh session.

Should work when switching windows as well (probably parsing the hostname whilst switching + `refresh-client -S`)

Comment: Partial answer: Ctrl-B `:set status-bg red` (although I suspect you're seeking to automate this better/easier...  might be easier to do by using a script that runs ssh)

Comment: `status-bg` and its friends was deprecated in 1.9. Use `status-style` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your ~/.tmux.conf add the following two code lines in sequence

Set the normal color

```
set -g status-bg colour5
```

Set the ssh color

```
if-shell -b ' [ "$SSH_CLIENT" ] ' "set -g status-bg colour6"
```